# TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable

Tags: function

So I tried to make Jarvis (Inspired by iron man) and everything was going well, until lines 32-39.
Here is the output:[Here is an image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kz37.jpg)

```
PS C:\Users\HP> & C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/HP/Desktop/Python/Jarvis_AI.py
<function take_command at 0x000001C3A659C7C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\HP\Desktop\Python\Jarvis_AI.py", line 42, in <module>
    run_jarvis()
  File "c:\Users\HP\Desktop\Python\Jarvis_AI.py", line 35, in run_jarvis
    if "play" in command:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 35, you're saving the function take_command to the variable command.  I imagine you're wanting to save whatever gets returned from take_command.

So on line 35, change
`command = take_command`
to
`command = take_command()`

So just adding the brackets to take_command.